# unknown device is mounted in /media/

Tags: mount, 18.04, disk

ubuntu 18.04
My user name is tim and in /media/tim I have a device I don't recognise.

It's mounted in a directory with a name which looks like a UUID, but no such UUID is listed in /dev/disk/

copy and paste the name:

admin:///media/tim/e5c1d6eb-e93a-4759-85d9-1f3227e39124

it does not list in

```
tim@moncrief:/dev/disk$ ls -l by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May 28 07:20 0CFD-D27C -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May 28 07:20 237b76b6-81cc-43b9-a1a8-4c4aa2ad6789 -> ../../nvme0n1p5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May 28 07:20 95932c74-0cb3-4003-8765-e6b55febb5b0 -> ../../nvme0n1p7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May 28 07:20 B21C00911C0052B1 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May 28 07:20 DA8402038401E33D -> ../../nvme0n1p4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 28 07:20 f0d9e048-72a2-4115-b287-f5adf1a6191f -> ../../sda1
```

I can write to it.

Comment: Is it empty? If so, it might be a "ghost" of a partition that you mounted some time ago. I would suggest to just remove it and see if / when it comes back.

Comment: Do you have any network attached storages ? Samba ?  Anything in `/etc/mtab` that helps shine light on this  mount point ?

Comment: thanks @dadexix86, I deleted it, and it has not reappeared.